# Getting enum Values by its index

Tags: c++, enums

How can I access each value of the enum by the index?

for instance,

```
enum food{PIZZA, BURGER, HOTDOG};
```

as we all know, the index of the first element starts from 0 unless initialized.

How can I get the string value of the enum from the index?

How can I get it to print the PIZZA?

```
cout << food(0);
```

I know it's not correct, but please advise me thanks.

Comment: enums don't have indices. They have a set of values that their instances can have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the string representation of an `enum` in c++.

You have to store them somewhere else.

**Example**

```
enum food{PIZZA, BURGER, HOTDOG}

char* FoodToString(food foodid)
{
    char* foodStrings[3] = {"PIZZA","BURGER","HOTDOG"};

    return foodstrings[foodid];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of doing that because there's no need to do that. Generally enums are used to replace integral values we use for example:-

```
int func () 
{
 //...
if (something )
  return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

could be replaced with

```
enum Status { SUCCESS, FAILURE };

Status func () 
{
 //...
if (something )
  return SUCCESS;
  return FAILURE;
}
```

for better readability.

If you want to get enum value by providing index then you can store index with enum values in some sort of map ( for unordered_map ).